# pagination in zend framework 1.1

Tags: php

am trying to do pagination using zend framework 1.1 and cant make it work.i have looked at diffrent tutorials but its so out of this world for me..here is my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
  $db=new Application_Model_DbTable_Database();
  $sql=$db->fetch_records();


  $paginator=new Zend_Paginator(new  Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array($sql));
  $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(3);
  $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page',1));
  $this->view->paginator=$paginator;
}
```

then i have this view script:

```
foreach($this->paginator as $book) 
{
     echo $book['firstname'].''.$book['lastname'];
     echo "<br>";
 }

 echo $this->paginationcontrol($this->paginator,'Sliding','pagination.phtml');
```

I'm able to see the first 3 records but when I add the pagination control I get an error. The pagination.phtml file is located inside the scripts directory The error I get is

```
an error just occurred, application error
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You mean `php`, right? Not `c++`...

Comment: yeah php...sorry about that..

Comment: Can you show us `$sql=$db->fetch_records();` what does it return.

Comment: thisis the print_r of $sql;Array ( [0] => Array ( [firstname] => joseph [lastname] => njuguna ) [1] => Array ( [firstname] => james [lastname] => mwanikiu ) [2] => Array ( [firstname] => capital [lastname] => fm ) [3] => Array ( [firstname] => kiss [lastname] => fm ) [4] => Array ( [firstname] => p [lastname] => uhuru ) [5] => Array ( [firstname] => k [lastname] => ujinga ) )

Comment: then It should work. I can't see any error. `paginationControl` c should be capital if you are using linux.

Comment: yeah it should be capital..is there a way to test whether the template file-paginationControl is being processed...coz one i introduce the paginationControl line..i get an error...